# GCS bucket access denied while in GKE node

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-storage

I am accessing data stored in GCS bucket while running Python within a container in a GKE node within the same project.

I can run `gsutil ls` **without problems**, but when I try to access the bucket with Python, I get a permission error:

```
raise exceptions.from_http_response(response)
google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/xxxxxxxx/o?maxResults=1&projection=noAcl&prefix=test%2F&prettyPrint=false: Caller does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. Permission 'storage.objects.list' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
```

I am listing the GCS bucket using the answer from @Robino in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37074977/how-to-get-list-of-folders-in-a-given-bucket-using-google-cloud-api). For brevity, I copied it here:

```
import google.cloud.storage as gcs
client = gcs.Client()

BUCKET_NAME = "abc"
blobs = client.list_blobs(
    BUCKET_NAME,
    prefix="xyz/",  # <- you need the trailing slash
    delimiter="/",
    max_results=1,
)
next(blobs, ...) # Force blobs to load.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the authentication configs were not picked by python. Calling `gcloud auth application-default login` solved it.